# handle JSON file with powershell (depth)

Tags: json, powershell

i want to loop through a JSON file and with each parentitem, i want to write the childitems to a SQL query.
The query works fine, but i dont know how to enter the childitem in a parentitem.

My JSON File looks like this

```
{
  "cp9385930" : {
    "macAddress" : "djxnkd",
    "productName" : "cp9385930",
    "serialNumber" : "cndndj"
  },
  "cp93875" : {
    "macAddress" : "dnnf",
    "productName" : "cp93875",
    "serialNumber" : "ndnd"
  },
  "cp94774" : {
    "macAddress" : "dncnd",
    "productName" : "cp94774",
    "serialNumber" : "xjxjr"
  },
  "jfiskn" : {
    "macAddress" : "cnfnd",
    "productName" : "jfiskn",
    "serialNumber" : "xhfn"
  },
  "zb9485" : {
    "macAddress" : "cndkkdc",
    "productName" : "zb9485",
    "serialNumber" : "dfsa3"
  }
}
```

I tried

```
$json = Get-Content -path c:\export.json | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I have trouble to enter the information in the parentitem - depth 1(?).
I've searched a while but cannot fix my problem. The Scripting-Guy cant help me with this.

Output:

```
cp9385930 : @{macAddress=djxnkd; productName=cp9385930; serialNumber=cndndj}
cp93875   : @{macAddress=dnnf; productName=cp93875; serialNumber=ndnd}
cp94774   : @{macAddress=dncnd; productName=cp94774; serialNumber=xjxjr}
jfiskn    : @{macAddress=cnfnd; productName=jfiskn; serialNumber=xhfn}
zb9485    : @{macAddress=cndkkdc; productName=zb9485; serialNumber=}
```

with `$json.cp9385930` -> and the other parentitemnames i can enter, but i dont know how to loop through it and send it to the query.

I think its really easy to handle. Please give me a hint :)

Comment: is there nothing more to the json i.e. { elements: { "cp9385930"  }: { items } ? Something that defines those names ( cp9385930 )

Comment: Are you looking for this `$json | flatten`. See [this](https://powersnippets.com/flatten-object/) link.

Comment: The problem is the JSON structure. There's nothing that defines each of those things are part of the same collection to iterate over. They are effectively distinct entries.

Answer (score 0):

Not really fix the problem, but its a workaround for my problem.

```
$request = get-Content -Path C:\export1.json | out-string | convertfrom-json
$request1 = $request | Get-member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select Name
```

I request all names via Select Name
Output:

```
cp9385930 
cp93875   
cp94774   
jfiskn
```

after the variable owns the names i go ahead with

```
ForEach($item in $request1){

$request.($item.Name).serialNumber
$request.($item.Name).productName
$request.($item.Name).macAddress

}
```

not the smartest way but i can query the json without changing the json structure in database

thx for your help!
Paul